# CSS - Positioning a block in the center when margin is not working

Tags: html, css

So I've been creating a layout for some anime-list website. It doesn't really allow anyone to edit the HTML, so I need to stick to using CSS only. The problem that I have is positioning the menu in the center horizontally and vertically up to some point. I have an idea positioning it vertically with em values, but horizontally it's still a mystery to me.

Here's what I've got: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ear9g1z7/1/)

Here's the website that I'm working on: [Website](http://myanimelist.net/animelist/Recuvan) (Note that it works correctly only in 1980x1020 resolution)

//EDIT - for some reason the margin property is not working at all, so setting the width/height to some values and then using a half of the margin propoerty is useless. I've tried editting the last question but I accidently deleted it while mindlessly 'accepting' the notifiers...

//FIX - Using the !important values to override some elements.

```css
/*
MENU HOVER
*/

#mal_control_strip:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}
#mal_control_strip {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 150px !important;
  height: 190px;
  top: 10em;
  left: 10em!important;
  background: none !important;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1)
}
/*
MENU
*/

#mal_control_strip * {
  font-family: Bebas Neue !important;
  font-size: 17px !important;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000000;
}
#mal_control_strip a,
#mal_control_strip a strong {
  color: #ffffff !important;
}
#mal_control_strip td {
  display: block;
  height: auto !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  width: 150px;
  border-style: none;
}
#mal_cs_otherlinks {
  border-bottom-width: 3px !important;
}
#mal_control_strip td div {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
#mal_cs_otherlinks div:last-of-type,
#mal_cs_otherlinks div:last-of-type span,
#mal_cs_links div {
  font-size: 0 !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#mal_control_strip div a,
#mal_cs_otherlinks div:last-of-type a,
#mal_cs_links div a {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#mal_cs_otherlinks div:first-of-type strong {
  font-size: 0 !important;
}
#mal_cs_powered,
#mal_cs_pic img {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<body onload=" " class="">
  <table id="mal_control_strip" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="mal_cs_listinfo">
          <div><strong><a href="/profile/Recuvan"><strong>Recuvan</strong>
            </a>
            </strong>
          </div>
          <div>
            <form action="http://myanimelist.net/logout.php" method="post">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$(this).parent().submit();">
    Logout
  </a>
            </form>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td id="mal_cs_links">
          <div><a href="/addtolist.php?hidenav=1" class="List_LightBox">Add to List</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/">Home</a>
          </div>
          <div><a href="/animelist/Recuvan">Anime List</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/mangalist/Recuvan">Manga List</a>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td id="mal_cs_otherlinks">
          <div><strong>You are viewing your anime list</strong>
          </div>
          <div><a href="/history/Recuvan">History</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/forum/">Forum</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/panel.php?go=export">Export</a>
          </div>

        </td>

        <td id="mal_cs_powered" align="right" valign="top">
          <a href="/">
            <img src="http://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/list-top-powered.gif">
          </a>
          <div id="search">
            <input id="searchBox" value="Search" type="textbox">
            <img src="http://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/magnify.gif" id="searchListButton">
            <input id="listUserId" value="4998632" type="hidden">
            <input id="listUserName" value="Recuvan" type="hidden">
            <input id="listType" value="anime" type="hidden">
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: What about creating your list [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/7h8s1uuq/)?

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is that on every resolution : http://bit.ly/1S84ksJ (look at the menu hidden "behind" the logo, you may want to zoom out of this .gif file). However, when the resolution changes, that's what I get: http://bit.ly/1O6oe5y. // Web designing is still a very fresh environment to my skills so thanks for the advice! Also, I'm not able to change the CSS id as on this website I'm only able to edit the CSS, not the HTML itself, so I'm kinda limited. I'm working on an external website to be able to use my own HTML, but it'll take some time till I finish it.

Comment: I'd rather use the full menu (even thouh I thought of shrinking it to 4/5 categories) as it just makes navigating throughout the website so much easier.

Comment: lol, that was just an example. What you have screenshots of is zooming the browser which is a little different than changing the resolution of the browser. My example centers through `auto` margins so it will stay centered at any resolution size (table, smartphone etc.).

Comment: I have 2 monitors and a laptop screen in here, so 1280x720, 1980x1020 and 1368x768. I just zoomed it in to show what happens... I will try using your method of positioning in a second, I thought you suggested me the way of designing the website, not solving the actual issue. Sorry for that.

Comment: http://phototive.com/uploads/327/22537/i20vtdh3s8snf67o.png - Your solution seems to be not working, the code just ignores the margins and the padding

Comment: you have `padding` and `margin` set to `0` in your screenshot, so of course it's going to hang out in the upper left hand corner. I'm using `margin: 0 auto;` in my example, not `margin: 0;`. If you define a width for an element setting the left and right margin to `auto` will center the element in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `#mal_control_strip`, if you change your `left` and `top` to `50%`, you can add `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`

```css
/*
MENU HOVER
*/

#mal_control_strip:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}
#mal_control_strip {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 150px !important;
  height: 190px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: none !important;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
/*
MENU
*/

#mal_control_strip * {
  font-family: Bebas Neue !important;
  font-size: 17px !important;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000000;
}
#mal_control_strip a,
#mal_control_strip a strong {
  color: #ffffff !important;
}
#mal_control_strip td {
  display: block;
  height: auto !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  width: 150px;
  border-style: none;
}
#mal_cs_otherlinks {
  border-bottom-width: 3px !important;
}
#mal_control_strip td div {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
#mal_cs_otherlinks div:last-of-type,
#mal_cs_otherlinks div:last-of-type span,
#mal_cs_links div {
  font-size: 0 !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#mal_control_strip div a,
#mal_cs_otherlinks div:last-of-type a,
#mal_cs_links div a {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#mal_cs_otherlinks div:first-of-type strong {
  font-size: 0 !important;
}
#mal_cs_powered,
#mal_cs_pic img {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<table id="mal_control_strip" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="mal_cs_listinfo">
        <div><strong><a href="/profile/Recuvan"><strong>Recuvan</strong>
          </a>
          </strong>
        </div>
        <div>
          <form action="http://myanimelist.net/logout.php" method="post">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$(this).parent().submit();">
    Logout
  </a>
          </form>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td id="mal_cs_links">
        <div><a href="/addtolist.php?hidenav=1" class="List_LightBox">Add to List</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/">Home</a>
        </div>
        <div><a href="/animelist/Recuvan">Anime List</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/mangalist/Recuvan">Manga List</a>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td id="mal_cs_otherlinks">
        <div><strong>You are viewing your anime list</strong>
        </div>
        <div><a href="/history/Recuvan">History</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/forum/">Forum</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/panel.php?go=export">Export</a>
        </div>

      </td>

      <td id="mal_cs_powered" align="right" valign="top">
        <a href="/">
          <img src="http://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/list-top-powered.gif">
        </a>
        <div id="search">
          <input id="searchBox" value="Search" type="textbox">
          <img src="http://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/magnify.gif" id="searchListButton">
          <input id="listUserId" value="4998632" type="hidden">
          <input id="listUserName" value="Recuvan" type="hidden">
          <input id="listType" value="anime" type="hidden">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That ruins everything lol. See what happens > http://phototive.com/uploads/327/22522/0zt1cmvjwxwnxkf8.png // I've given you the website address so you can play around with it if you wish to.

Comment: Seems your left is being overridden, try adding `!important` or remove whatever is overriding it

Comment: Thanks! That phrase made me do more research about the !important function, now it seems to be perfect! To think that the solution was so easy... I've added the !important thing to my left and also to my transform. Thank you, again!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help.  Please could you accept this answer by clicking on the tick below the number at the top of the answer.  Thanks

Comment: I would also have to advise you, if you can help it you should always try to avoid using the `important` override as it becomes a nightmare to maintain if your site gets larger and more styles are added - this is a good article of when you should use it: https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: Done. +I will think of not using !important when creating my website that I've talked about in the comments below my question, see you soon (I guess)!

Comment: hahaha good luck!  This article about css specificity may help you avoid using important: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 0):

To fix the margin issue:under #mal_control_stip

Remove

- position: absolute;

Then
Add

- margin:auto;
- margin-top:50%;
- top: -95px;